# C++ variant of UNIX select() function?

Tags: c++, select

Is there such a thing?

I am working on a project in C++ where multiplexing on many sockets seems to be the way to go. I am soon approaching the part where I will have to implement said multiplexing.

If I really have to, obviously I well end up using `select()`. Has anyone had experience using or implementing similar functionality to `select()` in C++?

Comment: Writing a more user-friendly wrapper around `select()` isn't too difficult -- here's one that I wrote:  https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/util/SocketMultiplexer.h https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/util/SocketMultiplexer.cpp. (it also contains #ifdef's for code to alternatively use either poll(), epoll(), or kqueue() to implement the same C++ API, but you can strip all that stuff out if you only want a wrapper for `select()`)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks for the share, Jeremy.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Just following up: your code makes sense for the most part, though I am not afraid to admit that I am not a very experienced developer. That said, I would like to implement my own SocketMultiplexer for my application, and not simply copy what you have written. Would you mind sharing some thoughts on your initial approach in the design phase? How does one go about implementing such a system where I/Os from several sockets can all be routed to a single socket? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thing you'll need to do is understand how `select()` works -- it's not about routing data from one socket to another, it's about having a call that returns only when there is some work to be done on at least one of your sockets (and telling you which sockets are ready to be read/written from when it does).

Comment: Btw that class is part of this package at github:  https://github.com/jfriesne/muscle -- you might want to clone that package and then examine/compile/play with the example program at html/muscle-by-example/examples/socketmultiplexer/example_1_tcp_echo_server.cpp  to get a feel for how SocketMultiplexer (and therefore, select()) work to allow multiple TCP connections to be managed by a single thread.

Comment: Other than that, the traditional way to learn good design is by first creating a lot of bad design -- when you write some code and then find it painful to use or maintain, be sure to think about *how/why* it is causing you pain, and how you might change it to make it less painful.  Repeat until the pain goes away, and at that point you might have a good design.  (Don't be afraid to throw out or drastically rewrite code once you've seen why it is problematic and have come up with a better approach to replace it)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thank you, much appreciated!